# Golang access CLIENT socket of an http connection

Tags: sockets, http, go

I have an HTTP client performing requests normally to an endpoint and waiting for the response.

However, I want to read responses using the underlying socket and not the response returned by the "Do" request.

I tried to create an `httpClient` and pass a pre-connected socket, but it didn't work since I can't read anything on that socket.

**How can I access/set the underlying socket and read data from there?** (I also noticed that Dial is deprecated)

```
//Create socket and HTTP client
socket, socketErr := net.Dial("tcp", ipAddress+":"+fmt.Sprint(port))
httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
                return socket, socketErr
            },
        },
    }
//Perform the request
res, reqErr:= httpClient.Do(request) //GET, POST, etc.
//Read response bytes from socket
for {
    bytesR, _ := bufferIO.ReadByte()
    fmt.Print(string(bytesR))
}
```

Comment: Why do you connect via http when you need a (lower level) TCP connection?

Comment: The protocol used by the service with which I'm interacting is HTTP. However, it has some peculiarities, so I need to access the underlying socket

Comment: I think you need to think the other way around. Just do HTTP over TCP manually so you have full control where you need it.

Comment: @Rob Is there a way to convert an HTTP request (golang struct) in a byte array or I have to do it manually?

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1: you mean like [`Request.Write`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Write)?

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 this sounds like an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/) and you seem to be asking about how to do your solution?  Would you be interested in describing the underlying problem that makes you think you have to handle your own HTTP protocol stuff?

Comment: I solved it by directly writing on the socket. Since my HTTP service can respond 102,  I should wait for subsequent responses before finishing the call. However normal HTTP clients stop at the first response

Comment: I stand corrected https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36734